# Toshiba Laptop tells me to insert boot media in selected boot media device and press a key

Tags: windows-7, hard-drive, boot, laptop

Around 7 months ago i dropped my pc from knee high on the carpet and it went to a blue screen.  When i dropped it i was playing the game black ops 2.  In an attempt to fix it I held down the power button until it turned off then took out the battery.  After that it just wouldn't load so i decided to wipe it by holding down "0" when turning it on.  It gave me a lot of warnings and i was stupid enough to ignore them.  I have no back ups of my pc on anything.

So now every time i start up my laptop is says "Reboot and Select proper Boot device or Insert Boot Media in selected Boot device and press a key."   Above that it says PXE-M0F : Exiting PXE ROM.

We took it to some pc tech guys and after several tests they couldn't do anything.  They never told me that there was anything wrong with the hard drive or the connections inside.

I have no idea what to do and if  anyone could tell me ways i could fix this it would be very much appreciated.

Comment: Did my answer help you at all?

Answer (score 0):

If by wipe you mean clear the contents of your hard drive, it will have wiped the Operating System for the device. This means that it wont be able to run Windows as it is not installed. if you have no back up disks or install disks that you should have got with the machine, then the only way to make it function will be to buy a new copy of Windows. you could also use a downloaded installer for Windows if you have the product key on the bottom of your machine, this will save you £80 pound upward (Depending on whether you chose windows 7, 8 etc). Although this will obviously require a working computer to download.

If the wipe Option was just to restore to factory default, this may indicate that the Hard Drive was damaged indefinitely due to the drop and is unable to read. you may need a new hard drive and use the first method above.

Comment: Ill be sure to try it, thanks so much for the help.

Comment: When downloading the new windows 7 off the internet can i install it from a thumb drive?  If not a thumb drive a cd?

Comment: yeah you can run it from any removable storage media but be careful as I have had problems in the past with making a CD Bootable you need to make sure that the BIOS can find a boot order on the CD. It may be best to use an "ISO image" file of the OS.